# MDX - Drill down in a hierarchy to the last level having the member caption containing "#"

Tags: ssas, mdx, bids

I have a UserHierarchy, and when the member caption of the current level contains a "#" in the name, is resembles a particular user type. The UserHierarchy, contains up to 5 levels.

I would like to display drilled down data, but only for these particular user types, hence only those captions which have "#". I would also want to aggregate the children's data.

Is there a simple way in MDX to accomplish this?

Example :

```
#User1 €2
---#User2 €6
---------User4 €9
---------User5 €4
---#User3 €2
---------User6 €4
---------User7 €4
```

I would like to display figures, for themselves and children like this. To understand, I included where the figures were obtained from :

```
#User1 €2
---#User2 €19 (Obtained from : €6 + €9 + €4)
---#User3 €10 (Obtained from : €2 + €4 + €4)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
non empty(
 distinct(
  descendants({[Product].[Category].children}) *
    {filter([Product].[Subcategory].members,
      instr([Product].[Subcategory].currentmember.member_caption, 'T') = 1)
    } 
  * descendants({[Product].[Product].children})
 )
)
on rows  from cube
```

Result with detailed info:

[image: result]

"Second result:

Here i have deleted the row:

```
* descendants({[Product].[Product].children})
```

I think that´s what you want since it shows the totals of the children.

[image: result2]

You need to exchange the 'T' for your '#' then also the dimension names and what you want to show as a measure.

Comment: In your answer I see [Product].[Category], and [Product].[Subcategory]. Which one is the hierarchy? Or [Product] is a hierarchy in general, and [Category] is level 1, and [SubCategory] level 2?

Comment: The Product is the Dimension then on level 1 I have Product, Category and SubCategory.

Comment: Your second result, is what I am after.

However, I cannot get it to work because I am using a hierarchy within the dimension. My MDX below : 

SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    { 
     [measures].[comp money in] 
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES parent_unique_name  ON COLUMNS,
non empty(
 distinct(
  descendants({[Dim User].[UserHierarchy].children}) *
    {filter([Dim User].[UserLevel2].members,
      instr([UserLevel2].currentmember.member_caption, '#') = 1)
    } 
  * descendants({[Dim User].[UserDesription].children})
 )
)
on rows  from [Activities]

Comment: you have deleted row: * descendants({[Dim User].[UserDesription].children}) ?

Comment: yes. My dimension is named [Dim User], I have a hierarchy [UserHierarchy] containing 5 levels, each attribute named [UserLevel1], [UserLevel2] etc etc... I tried to apply your query to mine but doesn't seem to work

Comment: The query is just not returning a result set. How would the query appear in my case? I cannot understand your case [Product], [Category] and [SubCategory]. Is this a hierarchy within the dimension? Or are these just attributes? Could you mockup what the MDX in my case should look like, with or without an inner hierarchy?

Comment: Hi @daniel_aren my hierarchy is a ragged hierarchy, and I want to drill down based on a condition. Let's say one node I have users having a # till level 5, and on another node they only go to level 2. How can I accomplish this? I have tried using a drill down action with a condition - but to no avail.